# GNU Emacs23: cedet troubles

Tags: emacs, cedet

Since I switched to CEDET as shipped with recent emacs release (23.2), CEDET does not work reliably anymore. For example I am no longer able to regenerate an EDE project.

After looking aroud, it seems that all CEDET templates are missing from the tarball. Does anyone know how I can workaround this ?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to download the templates from the CEDET CVS repository for your Emacs install.  They are here:

EDE Templates:

http://cedet.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cedet/cedet/ede/templates/

Base SRecode Templates:

http://cedet.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cedet/cedet/srecode/templates/

Comment: Is there any reason not to include them directly into emacs' repository ?

Comment: I would guess it was an oversight during the merge, or creation of the .tar file.